# Would a ticket from Bangkok to a European destination be sufficient proof of onward travel arrangements to be admitted into Malaysia?

Tags: visas, air-travel, thailand, malaysia, denial-of-entry

I'm arriving in to Kuala Lumpur from Singapore in a few days and have yet to sort out a travel itinerary for my time in Malaysia. I'm reluctant to book a flight from the capital to Thailand (my rough plan) at the moment as I'm unsure of how long I'm going to spend there/where I'll be going/what I'll be doing/what mode of transportation I want to take etc. Ideally I'd just like to sort this out once I'm there but most airlines won't let you check in unless you have proof of departure, so the onward travel requirement puts a spanner in the works for that.

Would a flight from Bangkok (or any other country, for that matter) out of the region be sufficient when I've made no actual plans to enter Thailand and leave Malaysia as yet? If not, is there a course of action I can take that doesn't restrict my flexibility too badly whilst satisfying the entry requirements? Thanks.

Edit: I'm a British national so can visit Malaysia, Singapore and Thailand visa free.

Comment: What is your nationality? What kind of visa do you have for Malaysia? Do you have a visa for Thailand?

Comment: Could you not just buy a cheap train ticket online for a trip back to Singapore, which you then don't use?

Comment: @Aditya Somani

Should have mentioned I'm a British national so I get 30 days visa free

Comment: First, I'm Spanish and I've enter in Malaysia without any return ticket, so I'm pretty sure you won't have any problem. And second, if you are unsure, do what @Gagravarr say: buy the cheapest ticket you can to go out (flights from KUL to SIN are around 10 pounds!!).

Answer (score 2):

When arriving in Kuala Lumpur, you will get a (free) VISA ON ARRIVAL stamp in your british passport for 90(!) days!

There is no need for an onward ticket, except when you fly from Singapore through Vietnam with Vietnam airlines. They require you to have booked a ticket leaving Malaysia.
Even then, no flight ticket is necessary, since you can book a long distance bus ticket, e.g. with www.malaysiabus.com leaving to Thailand.